# Can a minor burn influence blood/fecal test results?

Tags: blood-tests, burns

If a person sustained a minor burn on their hand from touching a hot object (2-3 hours after the burn there is only some red skin and little pain), and is meant to do blood and fecal tests in the couple of days after the event, could the tests be affected by the event (the burn)?

I am mostly concerned regarding tests which test for inflammation (mainly blood C-reactive protein and fecal calprotectin tests) as I was concerned perhaps the body's response to the burn could elevate these, but beyond that I am interested in the following, quite common, tests (all of which are in blood, so the main fecal test of interest is fecal calprotectin mentioned before): complete blood count, blood biochemistry panel, vitamin tests, metals (e.g. lead, iron, chromium), thyroid function tests.

Comment: I imagine only a study with the same scenario as you've described and including several participants could reliably answer your question. A local mild burn might affect CRP levels and maybe WBC but not likely any other blood test result you've mentioned. I don't see any logic why it would affect any stool test.

Comment: The first paragraph contains a valid question, but the rest is far too broad. Can you please edit this to ask a single, answerable question? I would suggest deleting everything after the first paragraph.